# What does it mean to adjust for short-run liquidity in finding risk-free rate of return

Tags: return

> Risk-free rate of return should equal the expected long-run growth rate of the economy with an adjustment for short-run liquidity.

What is meant by the last phrase, "adjustment for short-run liquidity"?

Comment: Can you give a reference for this? Did you read this somewhere?

Comment: yes!..read it in "Analysis of Investments and Management of Porfolio" by Reily and Brown